# Filter difference between 2 images?

Tags: java, image, image-manipulation

I am trying to filter out the difference between 2 images (Screenshots).
Unfortunately I have absolutely no experience in Java and images and have no real idea what to look for.

Are there ready-to-use classes for that?

What I am expecting is something like:

```
Image imgA = new (pathToA);   // Image with for instance 500kb
Image imgB = new (pathToB);   // Image with for instance 500kb
Image imgC = ImageFilter.filterDifference(imgA, imgB);   // Only the difference between imgA and imgB and therefore for instance 20kb
```

**Edit:**

Example: Anyway, what I mean with difference is the visual difference between the to images (Screenshots). If I have one screenshot with 5 icons in a folder and then do another screenshot with 1 icon more, then I want imgC to only show this new icon.

**Edit 2:**

Clarification: I only want the difference between 2 Screenshots in a new image.

**Edit 3:**

Some kind of code that would look like this one (Code does not work):

```
private BufferedImage getImageDifference(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
    if (img1.getWidth() == img2.getWidth() && img1.getHeight() == img2.getHeight()) {
        BufferedImage img3 = new BufferedImage(img1.getHeight(), img1.getWidth(), img1.getType());
        for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
                if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(x, y))
                    //return false;
                    img3.setRGB(x, y, img2.getRGB(x, y));
            }
            return img3;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this downgrade of -1? This is an absolutely legitimate question! There is no way to ask better, when there is no previous knowledge! Anyway, what I mean with difference is the visual difference between the to images (Screenshots). If I have one screenshot with 5 icons in a folder and then do another screenshot with 1 icon more, then I want imgC to only show this new icon.

Comment: Why the new icon; why not the white pixels in the place that the icon is in in the other screenshot? (that's also the "difference") Have you ever seen an algorithm that can do this?

Comment: I only want the difference between 2 Screenshots in a new image.

Comment: "The difference between 2 screenshots" is not a detailed to come up with an algorithm. SO is a programming forum, so you're expected to be able to describe your problem in a way that allows a specific answer to be given. As it stands now, without defining what you mean with "difference" in a way that can actually be implemented, the question is too broad.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit overasked in terms of where the bits of missing information in my posting are. Better would be to get questions! Anyway, above I provided a pixel comparison example between the 2 pictures, then creating a new one with _only_ the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in screenshots you can expect that the difference image would be minimal. This usually is true for small time intervals but it's highly uncertain for larger. Imagine your desktop when using a certain application and in a few seconds while continuing to use the same application and on the other hand the case where you use a different application. This parts explains I guess the file sizes you provide for your images. The difference image could be saved in greyscale format for this.

I don't know if there is some ready library for this. I would suggest this (simple) approach as a kick point:

1. just subtract the two images and
2. threshold your difference image:
3. a) to keep only differences above a certain value.
4. b) to keep only those areas that have a certain amount of neighboring pixels differing (this would leave out any isolated pixel probably from noise)
5. You can further process your difference image depending on your needs.

Not a java specific solution I guess. If you don't have any idea you can start reading about `BufferedImage` for example